# [DBNETLIB][ConnectionRead (recv()] connection problems under VB6

Tags: sql, vb6, sql-server-2008-r2

We are experiencing some I/O problems in our network when trying to write data back to our SQL Server.
The error-message that is thrown:

```
[DBNETLIB][ConnectionRead (recv())
```

Our environment:

- SERVER: WINDOWS SERVER 2012 R2
- SQL-SERVER: MS SQL SERVER 2008R2 (80%)
- Client: Windows 8.1

The app is written in VB6.

BTW: I already disabled TCP CHIMNEY.

What is more, the error occurs only time by time (under Windows 8.1).
But, what is really strange: no problems occur under Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Are you trying to write a large amount of data as small database calls from within a loop?

Comment: It's an ERP-Software. As far as I know the source code of the program,
Updates are made to the datasase. It uses TSQL as well. Nothing special.

Comment: Data can be read from the database. Just the way back to the db, if you want to update the table, this error seems to occur (Only Windows 8.1 client). :) And no, data is not being written within a loop. All different data.

Comment: Are named pipes an option?